# Is the function $ f \colon X \to f(X), f(x) =x^3 $ continuous, uniformly continuous

Tags: general-topology, continuity, uniform-continuity

Let $$ X = \big( [0,1]  \cap 
\mathbb{Q} \big) \cup \left\{ 1+ \frac1n \middle|\  n \in \mathbb{N} \right\} $$ be a subspace of $ \mathbb{R} $. Is the function $$ f \colon X \to f(X), f(x) =x^3 $$ continuous, uniformly continuous? It kinda seems like it is continuous because it is an elementary function. I'm stuck.

Comment: (your latex had an error so I edited it, do check if it is what you intended.)

Comment: Show that if $x^3$ is continuous on $[0,2]$, then it is continuous on the subset $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function $x^3$ is uniformly continuous on any compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and hence on any bounded subset.

Answer (score 1):

If $x,y \in X$ then $0 \le x,y \le 2$ and therefore

$$|f(x)-f(y)|=|x-y| (x^2+xy+y^2) \le |x-y|(4+4+4 )= 12|x-y|.$$